# Garbage Collector deletes an int but saves a list

Tags: python, garbage-collection

I am curious why, if I make a list and an int and try to find it in gc.get_objects(), I found only the list. Code:

```
import gc

a = 1
b = [1, 2, 3]
for obj in gc.get_objects():
    if a is obj:
        print('Found: a')
    if b is obj:
        print('Found: b')
print(a)
```

Outputs only:

Found: b

1

There's no `a` in `gc.get_objects()` but of course I can still access it.

Comment: Not all objects are tracked by the garbage collector, indeed, this is stated in the `gc` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.is_tracked). Python only uses the garbage collector to clean up objects that might be missed by reference counting (i.e. caused by cyclic references).

Comment: So read more [here](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-does-python-manage-memory.htm). Note: "The standard C implementation of Python uses reference counting to detect inaccessible objects, and a separate mechanism to collect reference cycles, periodically executing a cycle detection algorithm which looks for inaccessible cycles and deletes the objects involved." that separate mechanism *is what is exposed* `gc`. As an optimization, many types like `int`, and `str` aren't even tracked by the cycle detector.

Comment: `gc.get_objects()` will not return a list of all objects. also numpy arrays will not be found by this function.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html):

> As a general rule, instances of atomic types aren’t tracked and instances of non-atomic types (containers, user-defined objects…) are.

To be noticed that this is not absolutely the case. This citation is also added to avoid misleading:

> However, some type-specific optimizations can be present in order to suppress the garbage collector footprint of simple instances